# angularsjs state provider multi params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, session-state-provider

I am trying to build state provider that catch multi params but the issue is that i dont know how many params 
is it possible to catch them as object or array?
or the only solution is to catch it as string and separate them?

for example this is my provider

```
.state('app.confirmPayment', {
        url: '/comfirmPayment/:params',
        templateUrl: '/Views/ConfirmPayment.html'
    })
```

and  controller

```
app.controller('ConfirmController', ['$scope', '$state', 
    function ($scope, $state) {
        var self = this;

        console.log('$state confirm payment');
        console.log($state);
        console.log('$state confirm payment');

    }
]);
```

and want to catch all the params separated

```
/comfirmPayment/:age=15&name=erez.....  // can be more that i dont know
```

and can be more params that i dont know what they can be

thanks
hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're binding to the query parameters (see the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)), you don't access them directly through `$state` or `$stateParams`.

Suppose the url

```
cities?cityId=3&param1=value1
```

and You can handle this in your router config `$stateProvider` where you define states

```
.state('cities', {
          url: "/cities?cityId&param1",
          templateUrl: "cities.html",
          controller: "citiesController"
        })
// will match to url of "/cities?cityId=[any id]&param1=[any value]"
```

and finally You can have these parameters in the **citiesController.js** i.e

```
console.log($stateParams);
//Object {cityId: "3", param1: "value1"}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about the params that i don't know what are they you misunderstand the question

Comment: @Erez I have edited my answer please have a look and ask any question regarding it.

Comment: `objNeedsToBePassed` is the params obj that have all the params in your controller that need to be passed to another controller.

Comment: i will check but i dont use state.go cause i dont send the params. i just get them by url.
it will be the same?

Comment: How are you getting params in url in an angular app? You could just make an object of the params you need to pass into another controller using this method.

Comment: i get them when someone enter the url to my website it an example to know if its possible to do it?
i do request to somewhere and then i need to get back url with many params so i want to catch them if possible to array json or somethinhg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107634/discussion-between-erez-and-mjunaidsalaat).